# drush for installing new drupal project openshift rhc

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drush, openshift-enterprise

I need to install new drupal project in openshift rhc company, SO i installed drupal package from its application page and it automatically install drush  . so could i install new drupal project by using drush trough the ssh connection, i try to get the source code of the drupal site:from the page of :
https://www.drupal.org/project/openpublic
I used this code based of using  `drush help si` from this site (`www.drupal.org/documentation/install/developers`):

```
cd /tmp && mkdir tmp && cd tmp
wget http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/openpublic-7.x-1.x-dev-core.zip
unzip openpublic-7.x-1.x-dev-core.zip
cd openpublic-7.x-1.x-dev-core
cd profiles
mv openpublic/* ~/app-root/data/downloads/drupal-7.34/profiles/
cd ~/app-root/data/downloads/drupal-7.34/sites/default
mv settings.php settings.php0
#[drush2-drupal4ss.rhcloud.com default]\> env |grep IP
#OPENSHIFT_PHP_IP=127.7.97.1
drush site-install openpublic --db-url='mysql://[adminmYcHgNH]:[_ValXnyADQuM]@127.7.97.1/[drush3]' --site-name=Example
```

and i get this error:

```
[drush2-drupal4ss.rhcloud.com default]\> drush site-install openpublic --db-url
='mysql://[adminmYcHgNH]:[_ValXnyADQuM]@127.7.97.1/[drush3]' --site-name=Exampl
e
You are about to create a sites/default/settings.php file and CREATE  the '[drus
h3]' database. Do you want to continue? (y/n): y
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.7.97.1' (111)
Starting Drupal installation. This takes a few seconds ...           [ok]
WD php: Exception: Sorry, the profile you have chosen cannot be      [error]
loaded. in install_load_profile() (line 1372 of
/var/lib/openshift/54d7161ffcf933c4b3000060/app-root/data/downloads/drupal-7.34/
includes/install.core.inc).
WD php: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already  [warning]
sent by (output started at
/var/lib/openshift/54d7161ffcf933c4b3000060/app-root/runtime/dependencies/php/ph
plib/pear/pear/php/drush/includes/output.inc:38)
in drupal_send_headers() (line 1233 of
/var/lib/openshift/54d7161ffcf933c4b3000060/app-root/data/downloads/drupal-7.34/
includes/bootstrap.inc).
Exception: Sorry, the profile you have chosen cannot be loaded. in install_load_
profile() (line 1372 of /var/lib/openshift/54d7161ffcf933c4b3000060/app-root/dat
a/downloads/drupal-7.34/includes/install.core.inc).
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.   [error]
[drush2-drupal4ss.rhcloud.com default]\>
```

SO i use this code (`drush make --prepare-install build-openpublic.make openpublic`) insted of `drush site-install ...` by this way :

```
cd /tmp && mkdir tmp && cd tmp
wget http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/openpublic-7.x-1.x-dev-core.zip
unzip openpublic-7.x-1.x-dev-core.zip
cd openpublic-7.x-1.x-dev-core
cd profiles/openpublic
drush make --prepare-install build-openpublic.make openpublic
```

after that it show me

```
    [drush2-drupal4ss.rhcloud.com openpublic]\> drush make --prepare-install build-
openpublic.make openpublic
Beginning to build build-openpublic.make.                            [ok]
drupal-7.34 downloaded.                                              [ok]
drupal patched with                                                  [ok]
992540-3-reset_flood_limit_on_password_reset-drush.patch.
drupal patched with                                                  [ok]
1355984-timeout_on_install_with_drush_si-make.patch.
drupal patched with 1369024-theme-inc-add-messages-id-make-D7.patch. [ok]
drupal patched with                                                  [ok]
1369584-form-error-link-from-message-to-element-D7.patch.
drupal patched with drupal7.menu-system.1697570-29.patch.            [ok]
drupal patched with 1441950-drupal_node_types_custom-8.patch.        [ok]
drupal patched with 2124397-drupal-file-upload-19-do-not-test.patch. [ok]
Generated PATCHES.txt file for drupal                                [ok]
openpublic cloned from http://git.drupal.org/project/openpublic.git. [ok]
Checked out revision appify_services.                                [ok]
Found makefile: drupal-org.make                                      [ok]
field_group-7.x-1.1 downloaded.                                      [ok]
Project references contains 3 modules: node_reference, user_reference, referenc
s.
references-7.x-2.1 downloaded.                                       [ok]
context cloned from http://git.drupal.org/project/context.git.       [ok]
Checked out revision c4d47fb08a5aa3f7a258adb10007906029cee44c.       [ok]
Project ctools contains 9 modules: ctools_access_ruleset, ctools_plugin_example
 bulk_export, views_content, stylizer, ctools_custom_content, ctools_ajax_sampl
, page_manager, ctools.
ctools-7.x-1.3 downloaded.                                           [ok]
ctools patched with                                                  [ok]
ctools-views_content-exposed_form_override-1901106_0.patch.
Generated PATCHES.txt file for ctools                                [ok]
Project panels contains 4 modules: panels_node, panels_ipe, panels_mini, panels

panels-7.x-3.3 downloaded.                                           [ok]
Project date contains 11 modules: date_views, date_context, date_tools, date_ap
, date_repeat, date_popup, date_repeat_field, date_all_day, date_migrate_exampl
, date_migrate, date.
date-7.x-2.6 downloaded.                                             [ok]
diff-7.x-3.2 downloaded.                                             [ok]
Project entity contains 2 modules: entity_token, entity.
entity-7.x-1.2 downloaded.                                           [ok]
entity patched with 2051079-1-entity-features_update.patch.          [ok]
Generated PATCHES.txt file for entity                                [ok]
features-7.x-2.0-rc1 downloaded.                                     [ok]
features_override-7.x-2.0-beta2 downloaded.                          [ok]
openidadmin-7.x-1.0 downloaded.                                      [ok]
pathauto-7.x-1.2 downloaded.                                         [ok]
strongarm-7.x-2.0 downloaded.                                        [ok]
token-7.x-1.5 downloaded.                                            [ok]
imce-7.x-1.7 downloaded.                                             [ok]
imce_wysiwyg-7.x-1.0 downloaded.                                     [ok]
Project views contains 2 modules: views, views_ui.
views-7.x-3.7 downloaded.                                            [ok]
Project nodequeue contains 4 modules: nodequeue_service, nodequeue_generate, sm
rtqueue, nodequeue.
nodequeue-7.x-2.0-alpha1 downloaded.                                 [ok]
sh: line 1: 199061 Segmentation fault      GIT_DIR=. git apply --check -p1 /tmp
make_tmp_1423383561_54d71c097eb17/1023606-qid-to-name-6.patch --verbose 2>&1
nodequeue patched with 1023606-qid-to-name-6.patch.                  [ok]
sh: line 1: 199069 Segmentation fault      GIT_DIR=. git apply --check -p1 /tmp
make_tmp_1423383561_54d71c097eb17/nodequeue_d7_autocomplete-872444-6.patch --ve
bose 2>&1
nodequeue patched with nodequeue_d7_autocomplete-872444-6.patch.     [ok]
Generated PATCHES.txt file for nodequeue                             [ok]
nodeblock-7.x-1.4 downloaded.                                        [ok]
Project xmlsitemap contains 9 modules: xmlsitemap_taxonomy, xmlsitemap_node, xm
sitemap_i18n, xmlsitemap_engines, xmlsitemap_menu, xmlsitemap_user, xmlsitemap_
ustom, xmlsitemap_modal, xmlsitemap.
xmlsitemap-7.x-2.0-rc2 downloaded.                                   [ok]
wysiwyg-7.x-2.2 downloaded.                                          [ok]
entitycache-7.x-1.1 downloaded.                                      [ok]
addthis-7.x-2.1-beta1 downloaded.                                    [ok]
twitter_pull-7.x-1.0-rc5 downloaded.                                 [ok]
conditional_styles-7.x-2.1 downloaded.                               [ok]
comment_notify-7.x-1.2 downloaded.                                   [ok]
Project google_analytics contains a module named googleanalytics.
google_analytics-7.x-1.3 downloaded.                                 [ok]
entity_autocomplete-7.x-1.0-beta3 downloaded.                        [ok]
Project context_field contains 2 modules: context_field, context_layouts_extra.
context_field-7.x-1.0-beta4 downloaded.                              [ok]
boxes-7.x-1.1 downloaded.                                            [ok]
boxes patched with boxes-1561196-q-path-ajax-issues-homepage-2.patch.[ok]
boxes patched with                                                   [ok]
boxes-form-title-jquery-dialog-error-ie7-8-1632916-02.patch.
boxes patched with boxes-cancel_validation_error-1758970-01.patch.   [ok]
Generated PATCHES.txt file for boxes                                 [ok]
views_boxes-7.x-1.0-beta8 downloaded.                                [ok]
tao cloned from http://git.drupal.org/project/tao.git.               [ok]
Checked out revision ef5e0b8a13fa6fe3c25b6d90fee3fd8c8b8b0630.       [ok]
rubik-7.x-4.0-beta8 downloaded.                                      [ok]
rubik patched with rubik_field_collection_wysiwyg-1525950-1.patch.   [ok]
rubik patched with                                                   [ok]
better_usability_for_nonvisual_users-1545882-1.patch.
rubik patched with rubik-fix-ie-filefield-input-1556392-1.patch.     [ok]
Generated PATCHES.txt file for rubik                                 [ok]
Project omega contains 5 themes: omega, starterkit_alpha_xhtml, starterkit_omeg
_html5, starterkit_omega_xhtml, alpha.
omega-7.x-3.1 downloaded.                                            [ok]
openomega-7.x-1.0 downloaded.                                        [ok]
Project delta contains 4 modules: delta_ui, delta_blocks, delta_color, delta.
delta-7.x-3.0-beta11 downloaded.                                     [ok]
delta patched with                                                   [ok]
breadcrumb_empty_despite_current_enabled-1532196-2.patch.
Generated PATCHES.txt file for delta                                 [ok]
omega_tools-7.x-3.0-rc4 downloaded.                                  [ok]
securepages-7.x-1.0-beta1 downloaded.                                [ok]
follow cloned from http://git.drupal.org/project/follow.git.         [ok]
Checked out revision 562227a760c8d8ff1bc6ccd579f8c26f00fbf164.       [ok]
context_bool_field-7.x-1.0-beta1 downloaded.                         [ok]
context_breadcrumb_current_page-7.x-1.0-beta2 downloaded.            [ok]
context_no_title-7.x-1.0-beta3 downloaded.                           [ok]
defaultcontent-7.x-1.0-alpha9 downloaded.                            [ok]
node_reference_view_formatter-7.x-1.0-beta3 downloaded.              [ok]
static_404-7.x-1.0-beta4 downloaded.                                 [ok]
webform-7.x-3.19 downloaded.                                         [ok]
Project captcha contains 2 modules: image_captcha, captcha.
captcha-7.x-1.0 downloaded.                                          [ok]
sh: line 1: 201712 Segmentation fault      GIT_DIR=. git apply --check -p1 /tmp
make_tmp_1423383561_54d71c097eb17/825088-19-captcha_ctools_export.patch --verbo
e 2>&1
captcha patched with 825088-19-captcha_ctools_export.patch.          [ok]
Generated PATCHES.txt file for captcha                               [ok]
Project recaptcha contains 2 modules: recaptcha_mailhide, recaptcha.
recaptcha-7.x-1.10 downloaded.                                       [ok]
link-7.x-1.1 downloaded.                                             [ok]
context_condition_admin_theme-7.x-1.0-beta1 downloaded.              [ok]
nodeconnect-7.x-1.0-alpha2 downloaded.                               [ok]
nodeconnect patched with                                             [ok]
nodeconnect_buttons_need_context_for_screen_readers-1362782-1.patch.
Generated PATCHES.txt file for nodeconnect                           [ok]
colorbox-7.x-1.6 downloaded.                                         [ok]
apps cloned from http://git.drupal.org/project/apps.git.             [ok]
Checked out revision b9d82b7bf5b4ebc7ba53324ce87082a84c3515cc.       [ok]
libraries-7.x-1.0 downloaded.                                        [ok]
colorbox cloned from https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox.git.      [ok]
```

But finally i could not see the installed project in the Address of my site and what else i must to do to it works!
you could see the site by this address:
[My site](http://drush2-drupal4ss.rhcloud.com)

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> Exception: Sorry, the profile you have chosen cannot be loaded.

happens when Drupal 7 can't access or find your profile in `profiles/`.

Please check the body of [`install_load_profile()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!install.core.inc/function/install_load_profile/7):

```
function install_load_profile(&$install_state) {
  $profile_file = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/profiles/' . $install_state ['parameters']['profile'] . '/' . $install_state ['parameters']['profile'] . '.profile';
  if (file_exists($profile_file)) {
    // ...
  }
  else {
    throw new Exception(st('Sorry, the profile you have chosen cannot be loaded.'));
  }
}
```